# Change the shortcurs for axis lock "x,y,z" after transforming ie:. "g"

Tags: customization, shortcut, axis

I´m trying to change the <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, shortcuts, usable after transforming something, usually using <kbd>G</kbd>, etc.

But after some trial and error, and extensive searches on the key binding panel, I'm a bit frustrated, there is a way to change those?

Would gladly change to <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd>, since they are much more intuitive for me.

Besides that is there a way to move in two axis? like X+Y? without changing the camera view.

Thanks guys.

Comment: "*Besides that is there a way to move in two axis? like X+Y?*" Yes press `Shift`+ Excluded Axis letter, like for XY plane `Shift`+ `Z`, The rest is hardcoded I think

Comment: Obrigado @Duarte , it would be so cool if it were not hardcoded, is there somewhere to make suggestions and requests for the devs?

Comment: Feature requests go on https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect